# How do I set Authourization header for TokenRevocationClient in IdentityServer3

Tags: asp.net-identity

When I execute via fiddler using ,

POST  http://win-ahf74lsi305:8443/core/connect/revocation

Header :

Accept: application/json
Authorization: Basic UmV2b2tlVG9rZW46UGFzc3dvcmQxMjM0
Host: win-ahf74lsi305:8443
Content-Length: 883

Request  Body:

Token= dskndsklaowlo8980809889900....

string tokenRevokeEndpoint = "http://win-ahf74lsi305:8443/core/connect/revocation";
var tokenRevokeClient = new TokenRevocationClient(tokenRevokeEndpoint);                             var response = await tokenRevokeClient.RevokeAccessTokenAsync("dskndsklaowlo8980809889900");

I get the response as invalid client because I am missing Authourization in my code,can anyone help to solve this please

My C# Code :